# For Eclipse Search/File, can I get back the number of files matched?

Tags: eclipse

When I use Search/File in Eclipse, I get the number of occurrences matched.  Is there also a way or alternatively a way to get back the number of files which contained 1 or more occurrences which matched the search query?

I could bust out the Mac command line, but I am asking from within this or a similar menu item within the Eclipse application.

Comment: I only know the following workaround for that: in the _Search_ view in the view menu select _Show as List_ , select all (Ctrl+A), copy it (Ctrl+C) and paste it into an empty text file to see how many lines (= files) there are.

Comment: @howlger Another good workaround thanks.  To share, in Mac console I am doing `grep -l -r {term} *.txt | wc -l` where {term} is the search term I am interested in.  Still, I would love an Eclipse solution to this.

Comment: I was talking about Eclipse. You can do it even without a text editor: in Eclipse in the _Search_ view select all (assuming _Show as List_ is selected), right-click and choose _Show In > Package Explorer_, then you get the number of files in the status bar as _n items selected_.

Comment: @howlger Ah, I got you.  When I am on Windows, I would automatically use Notepad++ for a task like that and so that is why I assumed external text editor.  I see now though that this would work with a new Eclipse window

Answer (score 0):

The number of files with hits is not displayed directly.

However, there is a workaround how to get the number of files in just two or three small steps:

1. In the Search view, in the **view menu**, make sure ***Show as List*** is selected (the default is *Show as Tree*)
2. **Select all** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
3. **Right-click** and choose ***Show In > Project Explorer*** (or *Package Explorer*)

As a result of this, the number of files *n* is displayed in the **status bar** as ***n items selected***.